# issue with install php54 on mac os x

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

When I run `brew install php54` command in terminal

```
brew install php54
==> Downloading http://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.15.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/php54-5.4.15
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.15 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/
If configure fails try --with-vpx-dir=<DIR>
checking for png_write_image in -lpng... yes
If configure fails try --with-xpm-dir=<DIR>
checking for FT_New_Face in -lfreetype... yes
configure: error: GD build test failed. Please check the config.log for details.
Error: uncaught throw `Failed executing: ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.15 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.4 --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/5.4 --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d --with-iconv-dir=/usr --enable-dba --with-ndbm=/usr --enable-exif --enable-soap --enable-wddx --enable-ftp --enable-sockets --enable-zip --enable-pcntl --enable-shmop --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg --enable-mbstring --enable-mbregex --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --with-zlib=/usr/local/opt/zlib --with-ldap --with-ldap-sasl=/usr --with-xmlrpc --with-kerberos=/usr --with-xsl=/usr --with-gd --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/opt/freetype --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/opt/jpeg --with-png-dir=/usr/local/opt/libpng --with-gettext=/usr/local/opt/gettext --with-snmp=/usr --with-libedit --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.15/share/man --with-mhash --with-curl --with-bz2=/usr --disable-debug --with-openssl=/usr --enable-fpm -
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Formula/abstract-php.rb:127:in `throw'
/usr/local/Library/Formula/abstract-php.rb:127:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:142:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:265:in `brew'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:651:in `stage'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/fileutils.rb:21:in `mktemp'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:647:in `stage'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:260:in `brew'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:121:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:43:in `main'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:12
/usr/local/Library/Formula/php54.rb:27
```

[Here is the configure file](https://gist.github.com/achempion/5608558)

`brew doctor` is clean

With `brew install php53` I have the same issue

Comment: Why you don't get MAMP?

Comment: I do not want to use it

Comment: Did you report the bug, as requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue. It was solving by executing

```
export LDFLAGS=/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib && export CPPFLAGS=/usr/local/opt/zlib/include
```

before

```
brew install php53
```

This points to correct zlib version path (installed by brew but not distributed with Mac OS X). Based on warning from zlib make:

> This formula is keg-only: so it was not symlinked into /usr/local.
>
> Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
>   parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
>
> Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
>   own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
>   build variables:

```
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include
```

Answer (score 1):

just run `brew link zlib --force`